# How to fill list view inside a user control from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a List view inside a user control, that user control placed inside MDI form, now what i have to do is i have to populate the list view based on  the MDI menu click. i tried the below method but its not working, the method getting triggered but the list view not getting update. Here is my sample code
User control

```
public ucQuickLaunch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListFill("Loaded..");
    }
    public void ListFill(string Message)
    {
        try
        {
            ListViewItem myitem = new ListViewItem();
            myitem.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString();
            myitem.SubItems.Add(Message);
            ListViewStatus.Items.Add(myitem);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

MDI Menu click

```
    public  ucQuickLaunch objQuickLaunch=new ucQuickLaunch();
    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmGeneral frm = new FrmGeneral();
        FrmGeneral open = Application.OpenForms["FrmGeneral"] as FrmGeneral;
        if (open == null)
        {
            frm.MdiParent = this;
            frm.Show();
            objQuickLaunch.ListFill("General button clicked");
        }
        else
        {
            open.Activate();
            if (open.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                open.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your custom control (ucQuickLaunch )  placed on your form (FrmGeneral). If so you need to add method for filling that control to your form:

```
    public partial class FrmGeneral : Form
    {
        public FrmGeneral()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ListFill(string value)
        {
            objQuickLaunch.ListFill(value);
        }
    }
```

and your menu:

```
        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmGeneral open = Application.OpenForms["FrmGeneral"] as FrmGeneral;
            if (open == null)
            {
                FrmGeneral frm = new FrmGeneral();
                frm.MdiParent = this;
                frm.ListFill("General button clicked");
                frm.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                open.Activate();
                if (open.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    open.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No @Pablo notPicasso my custom control (ucQuickLaunch ) placed inside the MDI form.

Comment: ucQuickLaunch is created but it is not added to any other control. Are you sure you are updating right control?

Comment: Yes.its added into the form MDI. FrmGeneral  is my second form.

Comment: So what is this code for:  ` if (objQuickLaunch == null)
            {
                objQuickLaunch = new ucQuickLaunch();
            } `

Comment: Thats i checked wether objQuickLaunch object null or not, i edited my question. kindly have a look it now

Comment: did you add this control to your form? `this.Controls.Add(objQuickLaunch);`

Comment: Yes the control added in my MDI form. I need to show the logs result inside the MDi(If user did anCRUD functions or menu click then i need to show its in user control), So based on the user activity in application i am trying to fill the user control list by using multi thread